# Suppose I want to exchange public keys between a client and a server. How can I encode a public key from string form to that of a JKS keystore?

Tags: java, cryptography, network-programming

So far I am trying by using an unprotected socket to send and recieve the server's public key and the client's public key. The goal is to have the client know the public key of the server and likewise the server to know the client's public key. After that I want to create new sockets via SSL and handle the rest of the communications securely. Both client and server have they private keys on their own environment.

Decoding the keystore produces a convenient string of the public key that I can send/recieve. How do I encode that string back into a keystore file that will remain on the machine of the client/server?

Another alternative is to send the entire file to the other end. This requires no encoding/decoding, but it requires the usage of more than one "non-secured" socket to achieve this. Is this a better alternative to just sending a string of the public key?

Comment: are you trying to implement trust-on-first-use for SSL?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the main focus. I want to know whether it's more optimal to send public keys as strings or as entire files via a socket.

Comment: It is almost certainly most optimal to send the certificate as a DER encoded sequence of bytes and have the receiver just import it into a keystore.